# What are the causes of the attrition rate of UNPO members?

Tags: united-nations, ngos

The Unrepresented Nations and Peoples Organization (UNPO) is an organization that represents a variety of groups and territories with limited international recognition, particularly in the UN, in order to promote their interests. It has under 40 current members. Notably, it also seems to have [roughly as many former members as current members](https://unpo.org/members.php), perhaps more, even excluding those members that achieved their goal of recognition as a UN member state. These former members are from various parts of the world and left at various times.

By contrast, the United Nations itself, for instance, has only lost around five members, all of which split into other UN member states, merged into countries that are UN member states, or (in the case of Taiwan) had their seat awarded to another UN member state, despite having existed for more than twice as long.

What accounts for the relatively high rate at which UNPO members have left the organization?

Comment: Do a lot of those dots look like viable autonomous countries?  Lots of them are small and indigenous in nature, and not infrequently landlocked within a larger country.  Quite possible these are vanity/protest/pressure projects, abandoned they get better treatment from their host country or when the next set of politicians come to their senses.

Comment: For two BC tribes I am familiar with: as far as I can tell, the [Tsimshian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsimshian) wiki doesn't mention their membership.  Neither does [Nuxalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxalk_Nation).  Though at least coastal, these are *small* places, the population of a small town at most.  I suspect most band members would not be impressed if they actually became independent - the BC tribal model has been to sign formal treaties, getting cash, land and recognized rights, with the provincial govt.  While not without problems it seems a lot more pragmatic in nature.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - The Nuxalk page does mention it, and it has not been edited for a few weeks, so that information was not added after you wrote your comment.

Comment: Darn.  My bad.  1st para too.  Look at their [membership page @ UNPO though](https://unpo.org/members/20832):  *At the time of their membership, the Nuxalk people suffered under environmental problems and infringement on their land rights. For instance, clear-cut logging permits were granted at a rate 50% above the declared sustainable yield level;*  Seems more like a protest/pressure membership rather than a full desire for secession.

Comment: I would theorize that half of these are ex-USSR minorities, which were taken off of that list during the Soviet dissolution democratization hype, despite actually being more vulnerable than ever due to fracturing of society and its economy.

Comment: @alamar - The organization was only created in 1991, so most groups that joined did so after the dissolution of the Soviet Union, and all groups that left did so after (well after, in most cases). Some of the groups that left by becoming UN member states were from Eastern Europe, but the former members are really from all over. Also, it's important to note that only two groups have ever been suspended—all others left voluntarily.

Comment: I think this is joke organization (meaning more joke than UN). "What we offer:

    6 months unpaid internship"

Comment: Ah, [joke status confirmed](https://unpo.org/members/18770). Special LOL @ their "taxation without representation" motto, like they want to drive all the dirty politicos out but to keep their tax munies XD

Comment: @FreeConsulting - I make no judgment on whether they should be taken seriously, but they do not appear to be a joke organization in the sense that they seem to take *themselves* quite seriously, as with many of the delegations that conform them (some of which represent fairly populous areas).